# Issues with multiple sticky / fixed headers/divs? (Jittering and positioning on scroll)

Tags: javascript, html, css, fixed, sticky

I'm trying to make a site with multiple sections. There are logos, that should take up the full screen. Then, as the user scrolls down, the logos should get smaller and shrink to the top of the screen, ***staying fixed to the top.*** They should push the section contents down so that they are fully visible.

The user can continue scrolling down to the next section. It should once again be the full page height, taking up the user's entire screen. It should push the previous logo header up out of the way, and repeat the same process, as the user scrolls down, it should get smaller, moving to the top of the screen, leaving space for the contents of the section.

However, unfortunately, the headers seem to be very jittery when I try to scroll down. The scrolling can even get stuck without moving the scrollbar with the mouse.

I have also found that after I scroll down past the second section, the first header pops up again.

Here is my site, with the minimal code to reproduce this problem:
[The Site](http://oblongimpassionedagent.fox_gdminggdmin.repl.co/)

The code is mainly copied from two w3schools tutorials, I have been trying to combine the two:
https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_sticky_header.asp
https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_shrink_header_scroll.asp

Any help would be greatly appreciated, and if anyone has any ideas on how this could be fixed, please, let me know!

**Update: I've figured out that the issue seems to be that the scroll offset, once the header shrinks, ends up being lower than the offset required to shrink the header. So it cycles and jitters between shrunk and not shrunk. How do I fix this?**

Code ***(No images, please open site link to test)***:

```js
// When the user scrolls down 50px from the top of the document, resize the header's font size

window.onscroll = function() {scrollFunction()};

function scrollFunction() {
  console.log(document.documentElement.scrollTop);
  if (document.body.scrollTop > 500 || document.documentElement.scrollTop > 500) {
    document.getElementById("title").style.fontSize = "24px";
    document.getElementById("title").style.height = "25vh";
    document.getElementById("title").style.position = "fixed";
  } else {
    document.getElementById("title").style.fontSize = "96px";
    document.getElementById("title").style.height = "100vh";
    document.getElementById("title").style.position = "sticky";
  }
  if (document.body.scrollTop > 100 || document.documentElement.scrollTop > 100) {
    document.getElementById("title").classList.add("sticky");
    document.getElementById("title").style.fontSize = "12px";
    document.getElementById("title").style.height = "10vh";
  } else {
    document.getElementById("title").classList.remove("sticky");
    document.getElementById("title").style.fontSize = "96px";
    document.getElementById("title").style.height = "100vh";
  }

  if (document.body.scrollTop > 960 || document.documentElement.scrollTop > 960) {
    document.getElementById("title1").classList.add("sticky");
    document.getElementById("l2").style.height = "50px";
    document.getElementById("title1").style.height = "10vh";
  } else {
    document.getElementById("title1").classList.remove("sticky");
    document.getElementById("l2").style.height = "500px";
    document.getElementById("title1").style.height = "100vh";
  }
}
```

```css
:root{
    --acol: #ffffff;
    --bcol: #eeeeee;
    --ccol: #dddddd;
    --dcol: #999999;    
}
html, body{
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    height: 100%;
    text-align: center;
}
#bodycontainer{
    display: flex;
}
#main{
    width: 95vw;
    height: 100%;
}
/* CARDS AND MAIN SCREEN*/


.title, #title, #title1{
    background: var(--bcol);
    width: 95vw;
    overflow: visible;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    margin: 0;

    align-items: center;
    position: sticky;
    top: 0;

    transition: 0.25s;
}

section{
    width: 95vw;
}
#container{
    background: var(--acol);
    width: 100%;
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
}
.card{
    flex: 1 0 21%;
    max-width: 250px;
    margin: 5px;
  cursor: help;
}
.logo.two, #l2{
    width: 50%;
    height: 50px;
  position: sticky;
  position: -webkit-sticky;
  display: flex;
  top: 70px;
}

/*SIDEBAR*/
#sidebar{
    background: var(--ccol);
    position: fixed;
    margin-left: 95vw;
    width: 5vw;
    height: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    font-family: "Helvetica";
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
}
#circ{
    width: 25px;
    height: 25px;
    background: var(--acol);
    border-radius: 100px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    z-index: 999;
}
#tabs{
    background: var(--bcol);
    width: 25px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    height: fit-content;
    border-radius: 25px;
}
.tab{
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    line-height: 25px;
    z-index: 1;
}
#wrap{
    position: absolute;
    width: 5vw;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <script src="script.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>

        <!--MAIN CONTENT-->

        <div id="bodycontainer">
            <div id="main">
                
                <!--ROLAND-->
                <section>
                    <h1 class="title" id="title">Roland PN-D10 Series</h1>
                    <div id="container">
                        <img src="PN-D10-01_Vector_2X.png" class="card">
                        <img src="PN-D10-01_Vector_2X.png" class="card">
                        <img src="PN-D10-01_Vector_2X.png" class="card">
                    </div>
                </section>

                <!--DAVID GARFIELD-->
                <section>
                    <h1 class="title" id="title1"><img class="logo two" id="l2" src="DGT.svg"></h1>
                    <div id="container">
                        <img src="David_Garfield_Vector_2X.png" class="card">
                        <img src="David_Garfield_Vector_2X.png" class="card">
                        <img src="David_Garfield_Vector_2X.png" class="card">
                    </div>
                </section>
            
                <img src="David_Garfield_Vector_2X.png" class="card">
                <img src="David_Garfield_Vector_2X.png" class="card">
                <img src="David_Garfield_Vector_2X.png" class="card">
                <img src="David_Garfield_Vector_2X.png" class="card">
                <img src="David_Garfield_Vector_2X.png" class="card">
                <img src="David_Garfield_Vector_2X.png" class="card">
                <img src="David_Garfield_Vector_2X.png" class="card">
                <img src="David_Garfield_Vector_2X.png" class="card">
                <img src="David_Garfield_Vector_2X.png" class="card">
                <img src="David_Garfield_Vector_2X.png" class="card">
                <img src="David_Garfield_Vector_2X.png" class="card">
                <img src="David_Garfield_Vector_2X.png" class="card">
                <img src="David_Garfield_Vector_2X.png" class="card">
            
            </div>

            <!--SIDEBAR-->

            <div id="sidebar">
                <div id="wrap">
                    <div id="circ"></div>
                </div>

                <div id="tabs">
                    <a class="tab" href="#a">A</a>
                    <a class="tab" href="#b">B</a>
                    <a class="tab" href="#c">C</a>
                    <a class="tab" href="#d">D</a>
                </div>
            </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Thanks!

Comment: We need to see a minimal reproducible example. In particular we need to see the relevant Javascript and associated HTML structure.

Comment: You can see it. Just open the site, go to the Dev Tools, go to Sources, and index.js is right there. I can add it to a code snippet I suppose.

Comment: @AHaworth the one issue is that no matter what even if I added the entire site to a snippet, there are no images, so the scrolling can't be replicated, meaning it can't be tested. The site itself is needed.

Comment: Anyone have any ideas?